# How to get values in Javascript array from ADFRichTable

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jsf

I have used my jsf page with Google Maps API V3. That will register house locations with their latitude and longitude and then next step is view this locations in Google Maps on JSF page. But I can't my ADFRichTable values into javascript array variable. How I can get this using Javascript? 
Thanks :)